# How to find out what is new and what has changed while comparing two dataframes in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes (over 1 mln records). Only ~10% of rows are different. I know how to find delta:

```
df1.subtract(df2)
```

But I would also want to know what records are new and what have changed. 
I know I can do this using Hive Context once I have delta but maybe there is a simple way to do this based on some pyspark functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What defines a row in your table? Primary key? Rank?

Comment: id field which is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform joins with `leftsemi` and `leftanti`

```
df = df1.subtract(df2) #diff dataframe
df.join(df2, how='leftsemi', on='id').show() #will print the modified lines
df.join(df2, how='leftanti', on='id').show() #will print the new lines
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I see that leftanti is not working in Spark 1.6.

Comment: @max04 same can be achieved with left. Just filter `where df2.id is null` to get the new and `not null` to get the modified

Comment: Yep, made it yesterday, forgot to comment there. Actually, it was pretty tricky. Had to use this `df1.join(df2, how='left_outer', on=df1.id=df2.id).filter(df2.id.isNull())` because this `df1.join(df2, how='left_outer', on='id').filter(df2.id.isNull())` did not work. It turned out that when I specify data frame in filter clause I have to specify it as well in the whole statement so in this case in `on` clause.